# Using LINK and UNLINK HTTP verbs in a REST API

Tags: api, rest, http-verbs

I am currently working on implementing a REST API. I have a resource model with a large number of relationships between the individual resources.

My question is: how do you link two existing resources to each other (establishing a relationship) in a RESTful manner?

One solution I came across was the use of the LINK and UNLINK HTTP verbs. The API consumer would be able to link two resources using LINK and following URI: /resource1/:id1/resource2/:id2.

The problem with this solution is the lack of support for the LINK and UNLINK verbs. Neither http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol mention the verbs, and they seem to be largely "forgotten". However, the original RFC 2068 does state that they exist.

I really like this solution. However, I'm afraid that many API consumers/clients will not be able to deal with the solution due to the lack of support for LINK/UNLINK. Is this an acceptable solution or are there any better and/or more elegant solutions for linking existing resources in a RESTful API?

Thanks

Comment: Why not create a Link resource that links the two resources?

Comment: That's another solution I was considering (it's pretty much handled in this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api). However, the problem is that for every type of relation, you have to define a new resource(type). This overcomplicates the resource model and isn't particularly pragmatic (since your API consumer has to be aware of a lot more types of resources). LINK/UNLINK doesn't overcomplicate it: establishing a relationship is very predictable and thus easier to use. However, if LINK/UNLINK are hardly supported...

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I use `LINK` and `UNLINK` in my (bespoke, company-internal) web app. I use https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-snell-link-method as my implementation reference.

I found that there are three types of clients:

1. Those that only support `GET` and `POST`, taking their cues from HTML's `<form>` element.
2. Those that only support `GET`, `PUT`, `POST` and `DELETE`. These take their cues from CRUD and RPC-pretending-to-be-REST type APIs.
3. Those that allow any method. The publication of `PATCH` as an official RFC has increased the amount of these, as has the growth of WebDAV, although sometimes category 2 clients support `PATCH` too.

Since we currently develop our clients in-house we don't have this problem, but I have looked into it and did consider the pros and cons before defining my API, in case we did want to allow third-party clients. My solution (since we needed to support HTML clients without Javascript anyway) was to allow `POST` to override the method by supplying a `_METHOD` field (`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) and then have my `post()` function on the back-end palm off to the appropriate function for the intended HTTP method. That way, any client in the future that is in, say, class 2 above, can use `PUT` and `DELETE` but wrap `PATCH`, `LINK` and `UNLINK` in a `POST` request. You get the best of both worlds: rich methods from clients that support it, and yet still support low-quality clients through POST-tunnelling.

Comment: I completely agree with this answer. I ended up implementing it just this way back in september and I am glad someone else came to the same conclusion. Thanks!