# Why does Spring not support RequestMethod.LINK?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

Why does Spring not support RequestMethod.LINK? How can I catch a query with a LINK method using @RequestMapping or another option?

Comment: It would be better if you would provide code snippet. Also ask specific question rather than theory.

Comment: Never before heard of such a request method, and also the internet standards (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231, Chapter 4.3 method definitions) don't know anything about it. Where did you hear / read about this new request method?

Comment: @ThomasKläger  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Methods/Link.html

Comment: screenshot Postman - https://prnt.sc/mj4x9z

Comment: I found an obscure reference to the LINK request method in RFC 2068 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068#section-19.6.1.2), dating back to January 1997. RFC 2616 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616 from June 1999) obsolotes RFC 2068 and removes the LINK request method. It seems that the LINK request method never got much traction - I doubt you will find any client (except PostMan) that can send this request method. So the question is still: do you need to support this request method?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247807/using-link-and-unlink-http-verbs-in-a-rest-api

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

decision

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
public int anotherMethods(HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (request.getMethod().equals("LINK")) {
        logger.info("LINK METHOD");
    }
    if (request.getMethod().equals("UNLINK")) {
        logger.info("UNLINK METHOD");
    }
    return HttpStatus.OK.value();
}
```

and add

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.httpFirewall(allowHttpMethodsFirewall());
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowHttpMethodsFirewall() {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowedHttpMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "LINK", "UNLINK"));
        return firewall;
    }

}
```