# POST to nested RESTful resources in Django

Tags: django, rest, backbone.js, tastypie

I'm building a REST Web service and I'd like to what is the best way (performance wise, elegance, and best-practice) on how to structure my resources. 
I have two models with ManyToMany relationship, so I could design my resources endpoints like follow (and as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api?rq=1) :

```
/api/v1/question/{q_id} #to access the question resource
```

and

```
/api/v1/question/{q_id}/answers/{a_id} # to access the answers of a question.
```

Now that's completely fine with a GET method, what if I want to create a new question with new answers, I have to send a POST request to the first URL and then *another* POST to the second?? Is it still considered a clean way of doing things despite the round trips?

P.S I'm using Django and still hesitating between [django-simple-rest](https://github.com/freshplum/django-simple-rest), [django-rest-framework](http://django-rest-framework.org) and [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie) with BackboneJS in the client side.

Comment: what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

`REST` is about resources. There is no best way to do it. I'll give you my Opinion (I run a big API since a long time).

For sake of simplicity I'd just create two resources:

- Question: `/api/v1/question/`
- Answer: `/api/v1/answer/`

Why? Because it's simple. Now, in order to make it performant and HATEOAS compatible, you could use different alternatives. For example, when you get a question, you could also get a list of answers:

```
GET /api/v1/question/{q_id}/
{
    'question': 'Should I use REST or SOAP?'
    'created_date': '...',
    'user_id': '99',
    'answers': [
        {
            'answer': 'REST, of course!',
            'user_id': 23,
            'resource_uri': '/api/v1/answers/818/'
        },
        {
            'answer': 'Are you nuts? Use SOAP!',
            'user_id': 12,
            'resource_uri': '/api/v1/answers/915/'
        }
    ]
}
```

You could use a similar scheme with a `POST`.

If you use Django Tastypie (which I've had a great sperience with) you could use fields to accomplish this simple task. You could get this working with 50 loc.

**Important:** Are you sure you have a `ManyToMany` between answer and question?

Comment: How would this work with POST in Tastypie with fields? And yes its ManyToMany field as every answer can belong to many questions too. Does it make sense?

Comment: Does it make sense? Not really. But it doesn't matter, it's your software and you know the requirements better than me.

Comment: With Tastypie: I assume you want to create a question with many answers, all at the same time. In this case you can use the hydrate method. It's totally viable.