# RESTful API: Modelling a collection of resources that have access to another resource

Tags: api, rest

I'm building a RESTful API that exposes my application's users as `users`.

My application also features 'documents' and each user has access to specific documents. I'm thinking the natural way to represent that is by exposing the accessible documents through `users/{user-id}/documents`.

However, from a usability perspective, it's important for my clients to be able to fetch (and modify) the users that have access to a specific document. Because of that I'm considering 'reversing' this representation to `documents/{document-id}/users`.

Do these (and especially the latter) seem like proper ways to model this relationship? If I do go with such a solution, how do I model 'granting access to a document'?

I'm leaning towards PUTing a pre-existing user (presumably acquired by GETing `users`) into `documents/{document-id}/users/{user-id}`. That seems unsatisfactory however, as I'll be doing an 'update' operation not to actually update the resource but to insert it into a collection. It is especially problematic in terms of semantics as I expect my server-side to ultimately *not* take into account the complete, sent user representation but rather only cross-reference the id with ids of pre-existing users in order to create an association.

On the other hand, I can't POST into `documents/{document-id}/users` as I'm not aiming at the creation of a new resource - I specifically *don't* want one to be created.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle many-to-many relationships in a RESTful API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api) (although I still would be interested in opinions about how PUT / POST semantics figure into this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The users don't really belong to the document resource, right? What you're really saying is these users have access to this document. So what should probably be returned from /documents/{document-id}/users is not a direct representation of the user entity, but instead some kind of representation of the user's permission to the entity. Perhaps inside of that representation is a link to the full user itself.

So, if you were returning the Collection+JSON media type, maybe you'd have something like:

```
{
  "collection":
  {
    "version":"1.0",
    "href":"/documents/document123",
    "items":
    [
      {
         "href":"/documents/document123/users/user3841",
         "data": [ 
                    { "name":"userName", "value":"John Doe", "prompt":"User Name" },
                    { "name":"permissions", "value":["Read"], "prompt":"User Permissions" }
                 ],         
         "links": [ 
                    { "rel":"user", "href":"/users/3841" }
                  ]
      },
      {
         "href":"http//whatever/documents/document123/users/user9387",
         "data": [ 
                    { "name":"userName", "value":"John Doe", "prompt":"User Name" },
                    { "name":"permissions", "value":["Read"], "prompt":"User Permissions" }
                 ],         
         "links": [ 
                    { "rel":"user", "href":"/users/9387" }
                  ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```