# How to manage relationship between 3 resources in REST API

Tags: api, rest, relationship, api-design

I'm creating an API based on REST concept but I'm still a bit confused talking about relating resources.

I've a website where people can signup in multiple groups and choose multiple roles. For example let's take people that signup in companies as scenario:

**Companies**

1. Facebook
2. Google
3. Apple

**Roles**

- Marketing
- Sales
- Development
- Customer support

So, when I want to create a user in a new company with certain roles, I would pass something like this into a POST request to /users endpoint

```
{
       "username" : "raffaele.izzia",
        "email"   : "example@email.com",
        "groups"  : [{
          "id" : 1,
          "roles" : ["Sales","Customer support"]
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "roles" : ["Sales","Marketing"]
        }]
}
```

With this approach, once I get some users from the API I always know in which groups/roles they are.

But what about requests on /groups endpoint?

If I GET /groups/google I should receive info about users/roles too. So it could be something like this

```
{ 
    groups: [{
        "id" : 2,
        "name"   : "Google",
        "users"  : [2,3,4,10,35,50] //role will be included in the single resource once you expand this collection
    }]
}
```

or maybe this:

```
{ 
    groups: [{
        "id" : 2,
        "name"   : "Google",
        "roles"  : [{
           "name"  : "Sales"
           "users" : [2,3,4,10]
        },{
           "name"  : "Marketing"
           "users" : [4,10,8,57]
        }]
    }]
}
```

What do you think is the best solution for this kind of relationships?

Answer (score 5):

This is a good question. Definitely a tricky situation.

I think the typical RESTful answer would be to think in terms of nouns, AKA resources. Even though you view this 3-way connection as a relationship between nouns, the connection itself is a noun. *That's* what you want your REST API to expose.

For lack of a better term, perhaps the name for your connection is an **assignment** (or an **allocation**, or whatever). E.g. "Alice working for Google in Marketing" is an assignment.

This now opens up new possibilities that should get you what you need.

E.g. an assignment object:

```
{
    "id": "...",
    "user": {...},  // e.g. Alice
    "group": {...}, // e.g. Google
    "role": "Marketing"
}
```

And fetching `/users/alice/assignments` returns a list of all of her assignments.

Similarly, fetching `/groups/google/assignments` returns a list of all the assignment objects for people working at Google.

The advantage to this is that now your assignments are truly first-class. You can now do things like keep track of *old* assignments, while having your main APIs return only *current* ones. Etc. (Props to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6333146/132978) for inspiration here.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea but here I don't see the connection between groups/people/roles. I mean, things that we should be able to retrive from a call are:

- Give me all the marketing and sales people of Google and Facebook
- Give me all the roles of a certain user
- Give me all the people 

For now i made it really simple. Just a simple resource that looks like this
{
    "id": "...",
    "user": "alice",
    "group": "google",
    "role": "Marketing"
}

Comment: I upvoted this as a good exploration of a simple problem domain and a proposal of a useful resource model containing hierarchies although the OP obviously did not understand your suggestion.