# How to handle two resources that are generally going to be requested with each other in REST?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

So say I have three models/tables: note, shipment and users. And I want to request pages of the shipments but I will need information from the associated notes (text, image, etc.) of a particular user.

What is the best way to handle this?

Should I create a nested resource like `/api/shipment/note` and add query parameters to it to specify the user id, pagesize, etc.? (Is nesting resources like `/api/shipment/note` valid REST? I have seen something like `/api/note/{noteid}/shipment` is valid but what about teaming up get alls)

Or should I request all the shipments from `/api/shipment` (specifying user in query parameters) and request the note information for each shipment from `/api/note/{noteid}`?

Or should I use `/api/user/{userid}/shipment/note`?

Or because I am very rarely going to be requesting the shipment resource without the information from the note, should I just add in the note info into the `/api/shipment` endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your use case has you querying both the shipment and the note together, it would be more efficient to combine the calls. This is also assuming that both sets of data come from the same data store.

To handle the cases where you don't need the `note` data, you can introduce a verbosity level or an `include` query string parameter to identify the extra data that should be included.

> api/shipment?include=note|foo|bar

OR

> api/shipment/{id}?include=note

Answer (score 1):

A couple more possibilities based on answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146869/define-a-rest-api-with-jpa-hibernate-entities-lazy-and-eager).

a) **Using a custom media type**:

```
GET /api/shipments HTTP/1.1  
Host: example.com  
Accept: application/vnd.company.full+json
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42147688/8543451

b) **Using new content-specific endpoints**:

```
/api/shipments/withNotes
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42146963/8543451

c) **As a combined resource**

This is basically **b**) but with a twist:

```
/api/shipmentsWithNotes
```

This is because it reifies the joined concept [as a noun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23823793/8543451).