# laravel 4 restful controllers manually

Tags: rest, laravel, controller

In the laravel docs they have explained using resourceful controllers for using REST and using verbs in the methods of the controllers.

I have manually listed all my routes like this:
Route::get('users/{id}/friends', 'UsersController@friends');

I am not using any resource just the method and the uri.
How can I make this restful? Or is it restful already? Then how do I call the methods in a RESTful manner? I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is nothing more than a convention on how data should transfer in the web. If you want to be all nitpicky about it check this out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Architectural_constraints

As for laravel, when you generate a controller via the CLI like so:

```
php artisan controller:make UsersController
```

Laravel automatically creates the boiler plate for the various actions you need to be handling (create, store, destroy, update and so on.) and then you can set-up your routes. Of course you wont need all for most controllers.

Here's a helpful set of links from Phillip Brown's blog:

http://culttt.com/2013/07/01/setting-up-your-first-laravel-4-controller/

http://culttt.com/2013/08/12/building-out-restful-controller-methods-in-laravel-4/

Comment: Could you tell me how will I call my urls from an app in a RESTFUL manner given that all my routes are mentioned as Route::get() or Route::post () ? I dont want to use any helpers from laravel.

Comment: Using the URLs RESTfully is a matter of using the right HTTP method. Anything you type into the browser will be a GET and will look for a Route::get(). Say to SHOW a particular user resource you can access `localhost/users/{id}`. Say you wanted to update that resource you will have to POST (PUT actually) to `localhost/users/{id}` but this time you would send in other data to update the resource with as post parameters as you would normally do in a form or ajax call. 

There really isn't nothing more to it. It's just using the appropriate METHODS (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) when accessing URLs.

Comment: BTW, PUT and DELETE are not globally supported which is why laravel spoofs this by automatically adding a _method hidden field to a form when you call something like:

`echo Form::open(array('url' => 'foo/bar', 'method' => 'put'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it RESTful, the simplest way in laravel is to do Route::resource('user', 'UserController), which automatically gives you the routes shown [on the laravel web page](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers).

However, if you are trying to look up the friends RESTfully you would want to make a /friends/ resource, and then register it as Route::resource('friends', 'FriendController'). For more on the relationships/friends side of things I would suggest reading [this question from 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api), while not laravel specific, it does answer questions about REST.

Comment: Yes you are using the resource method. But I have described all my routes manually as I hv described. Isn't there a way to use it directly in a RESTful way as I hv mentioned the method as get already.