# many-to-many relationships with fields in a RESTful API

Tags: rest, entity-relationship

I post the same unanswered question [from a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api#comment20524726_6328012).
Let's say I have 2 entities (Team and Player) and a many-to-many relationship (Registration) which have id_team and id_player fields but also others information like registrationDate.

`GET /teams/{id}/players` give me all players of a specific team

`GET /players/{id}/teams` give me all teams where a specific player is registred.

My first question is, can I create this resource :
`GET /teams/{id}/registrations` ?

My second question is, what about if I want get ALL registrations ? can I access them by this URI :
`GET /registrations` ?

Comment: It depends on how your application server maps URLs to Java classes and how you register the REST URLs. But seriously, what's your code so far and what's your actual problem?

Comment: I am beginer with AngularJS and I am still confused by how represent many-to-many relationships. This is a general question to know if it is common to access to a relationship by its own URI.

Comment: As you did not mention "AngularJS" in your question: How should anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use

```
/registrations/
/registrations/player:{pid}/
/registrations/team:{tid}/
/registrations/{rid}
```

So you should add a relationship resource and use flatten URI instead of creating a nested URI which is not so consistent if you want not just read, but modify this kind of resources.

*note:*

*Btw. this is analogous to relationship tables by relational databases, so I guess the idea won't be so new to you.*

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it is a good idea to use `/registration/player:{pid}/team:{tid}` and `/registration/team:{tid}/player:{pid}` if my database model has not id for registration ?

Comment: @AntoineMartin Ofc. you can use that kind of URI.