# Modeling a more complex entity relationship in a RESTful way (boxes and nodes)

Tags: rest, metadata, relationships

Here's an example to set up my question. I have a model which contains 'boxes', and they have a REST endpoint:

`/boxes`,
`/boxes/{boxId}`

This model also contains 'nodes':

`/nodes`,
`/nodes/{nodeId}`

Nodes can sit on the *borders of boxes*, and this is a many-to-many type of relationship. Having one node sit on multiple borders is a way to indicate that those borders (partially) overlap, but nodes also have other purposes.

[image: a quick visual example of boxes and nodes]

I'm trying to determine how to model this in an non-surprising, RESTful way. I can see a couple of ways to do this. But I'm  not sure which I should use:

1. Model `/borders` as a fully fledged entity type with its own endpoint. Have boxes reference four borders (top, bottom, left, right). Have borders reference a list of nodes. Have nodes reference a list of borders.
2. Model `/boxNodeRelationships` with its own endpoint, and have each such relationship point to a box, a node, and contain a 'border' field (an enum with four options).

Both are similar, and rather 'heavy' for their purpose. The alternative is to be a bit more ad-hoc:

3. Give boxes a list of `{ border, node }` objects. Give nodes a list of `{ box, border }` objects. These objects would be returned from `GET` calls and expected from `POST`/`PUT` calls, but would not be fully fledged types with an endpoint.

I'd like to know how a RESTifarian would solve this, as well as hear some pros / cons of these approaches. I'd also like to know if there are other approaches that are fundamentally different.

Comment: To find the most optimal way to model the API you need to understand use cases for which it's most likely to be used.

Comment: @astr: We need all kinds of ways to approach this data, really, e.g. getting all nodes on a border, getting all boxes connected to a node, getting all boxes connected to another box, etc. So I'm wondering about the most elegant RESTful API that provides full access to the data.

Answer (score 4):

I would create 3 entities:

- Box
- Border
- Node

And the relationships:

- A Box can have n Borders
- A Border can have n Nodes

So you could address them:

To get the first node: `/boxes/1/borders/1/nodes/1`

You could have some logic:

```
if /boxes/1/borders contain /nodes/1 and /boxes/2/borders contain /borders/1 then they intersect
```

And so on.

Comment: This is indeed one of the possibilities I considered and listed in my question. But what is the advantage of this approach over the other approaches? Would this be 'standard' in some sense?

Comment: How is option 2 against HATEOAS? It's actually a [common technique](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6324547/681588) for many-to-many relationships, as far as I can tell. The disadvantage of option 1 is that 'border' is a relatively useless entity; an extra redirection just for the purpose of solving this problem. They all have pros and cons. I was hoping for an expert's comparative analysis.

Comment: In my opinion relationships shouldn't be exposed as web service endpoints as separate entities (/boxNodeRelationship). These are not entities per se. These are not business objects.

Comment: Sure, not as end-points of themselves, perhaps. But the idea would be to have, e.g., `/nodes/{id}/boxNodeRelationships` and `/boxes/{id}/boxNodeRelationships`. (Making them available as endpoints would be optional, I guess, for completeness sake.)

Comment: I personally don't like this design. Why not `/nodes/{id}/box` - will return all boxes for the `id` node?

Comment: Because then I don't know which border of the box that node is attached to (one of four possibilities).