# Best endpoint design for associating

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, endpoint

I have 2 resources which each have a GET, and I would like to associate one to the other.

So lets say we have a list of users and a list of schools

GET  /api/users          /api/users/5

GET  /api/schools        /api/schools/8

each school can have a list of users. Also, each user can have a list of schools.
What is the best endpoint design to do an association?

eg: PUT    /api/users/5/schools   (send 8 in body JSON obj)

or  PATCH  /api/schools/5         (send user obj with just user list. Missing users in list will not be deleted)

Appreciate your help.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a many-to-many relationship between your user resource and school resource and in a RESTful interface, you can return results/documents that describe the relationships between these resources by representing those relationships as links.

Therefore a user can have a list of schools and you can represent that as `/api/users/5/schools` and that can be a list of links to school as in links to `school/{id}`.

And vice versa if a School has multiple users the `/api/schools/8/users` would can send back a list of links where each link points to a `user/{id}`

Technically that is just okay, but beware managing this would be a trouble because:

When you do modifying operations like PUT or PATCH, specially in case of PATCH, if you're using json as your payload format go for [JsonPatch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902). Anyway, in case of these, if you update one like `/api/users/5/schools`, the cache of the `schools/{id}/users` has to be invalidated, which in many cases might not be made sure.

The easiest way to go would be to go for a `membership` resource where you list out the membership between a user and a schoool, its easily cache-able and you can scale it easily too. :)

For more you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6324547/how-to-handle-many-to-many-relationships-in-a-restful-api)